# Is there an alternative to Numba for functions that use many features not supported by Numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I know Numba does not support all Python features nor all NumPy features.
However I really need to speed up the execution time of the following function, which is *block_reduce* available in the scikit-image library (I've not downloaded the whole package, I've just taken *block_reduce* and *view_as_blocks* from it).

Here is the original code (I've just removed the examples from the docstring).

block_reduce.py

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided


def block_reduce(image, block_size, func=np.sum, cval=0):
    """
    Taken from scikit-image to avoid installation (it's very big)

    Down-sample image by applying function to local blocks.

    Parameters
    ----------
    image : ndarray
        N-dimensional input image.
    block_size : array_like
        Array containing down-sampling integer factor along each axis.
    func : callable
        Function object which is used to calculate the return value for each
        local block. This function must implement an ``axis`` parameter such
        as ``numpy.sum`` or ``numpy.min``.
    cval : float
        Constant padding value if image is not perfectly divisible by the
        block size.

    Returns
    -------
    image : ndarray
        Down-sampled image with same number of dimensions as input image.
    """

    if len(block_size) != image.ndim:
        raise ValueError("`block_size` must have the same length "
                         "as `image.shape`.")

    pad_width = []
    for i in range(len(block_size)):
        if block_size[i] < 1:
            raise ValueError("Down-sampling factors must be >= 1. Use "
                             "`skimage.transform.resize` to up-sample an "
                             "image.")
        if image.shape[i] % block_size[i] != 0:
            after_width = block_size[i] - (image.shape[i] % block_size[i])
        else:
            after_width = 0
        pad_width.append((0, after_width))

    image = np.pad(image, pad_width=pad_width, mode='constant',
                   constant_values=cval)

    blocked = view_as_blocks(image, block_size)

    return func(blocked, axis=tuple(range(image.ndim, blocked.ndim)))


def view_as_blocks(arr_in, block_shape):
    """Block view of the input n-dimensional array (using re-striding).

    Blocks are non-overlapping views of the input array.

    Parameters
    ----------
    arr_in : ndarray
        N-d input array.
    block_shape : tuple
        The shape of the block. Each dimension must divide evenly into the
        corresponding dimensions of `arr_in`.

    Returns
    -------
    arr_out : ndarray
        Block view of the input array.
    """
    if not isinstance(block_shape, tuple):
        raise TypeError('block needs to be a tuple')

    block_shape = np.array(block_shape)
    if (block_shape <= 0).any():
        raise ValueError("'block_shape' elements must be strictly positive")

    if block_shape.size != arr_in.ndim:
        raise ValueError("'block_shape' must have the same length "
                         "as 'arr_in.shape'")

    arr_shape = np.array(arr_in.shape)
    if (arr_shape % block_shape).sum() != 0:
        raise ValueError("'block_shape' is not compatible with 'arr_in'")

    # -- restride the array to build the block view
    new_shape = tuple(arr_shape // block_shape) + tuple(block_shape)
    new_strides = tuple(arr_in.strides * block_shape) + arr_in.strides

    arr_out = as_strided(arr_in, shape=new_shape, strides=new_strides)

    return arr_out
```

test_block_reduce.py

```
import numpy as np
import time
from block_reduce import block_reduce

image = np.arange(3*3*1000).reshape(3, 3, 1000)

# DO NOT REPORT THIS... COMPILATION TIME IS INCLUDED IN THE EXECUTION TIME!
start = time.time()
block_reduce(image, block_size=(3, 3, 1), func=np.mean)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (with compilation) = %s" % (end - start))

# NOW THE FUNCTION IS COMPILED, RE-TIME IT EXECUTING FROM CACHE
start = time.time()
block_reduce(image, block_size=(3, 3, 1), func=np.mean)
end = time.time()
print("Elapsed (after compilation) = %s" % (end - start))
```

I went through many issues with this code. 
For example Numba does not support *function* type parameters. But even if I try to work around this problem by using a string for this parameter (for example func would be the string *"sum"* instead of *np.sum*) I'll fall into many more issues related to features unsupported by Numba (like *np.pad*, *isinstance*, the *tuple* function, etc.).
Going through each single issue turned out to be very painful. For example, I've tried to incorporate [all the code for np.pad from numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.21.0/numpy/lib/arraypad.py#L529-L876) into block_reduce.py and add the numba.jit decorator to np.pad but I got additional problems.

If there is a smart way to use Numba despite all these unsupported features I would be happy with it.
Otherwise is there any alternative to Numba for that? I know there is PyPy which I've never used. If PyPy is a solution for my problem I have to highlight I just need this single script *block_reduce.py* to run with PyPy. The rest of the project should be run with CPython.
I was also thinking of creating a C module extension, which I've never done. But if it's worth trying I will do.

Comment: If almost all your runtime is in numpy functions anyway, why would you expect numba to help? There's very little in here that would benefit from jit. Why not profile your code and then decide what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried running detailed profiling of your code? If you are dissatisfied with the performance of your program I think it can be very helpful to use a tool such as [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) or [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy). This can identify bottlenecks in your program and which parts specifically need to be sped up.

That being said, as @CJR said, if your program is spending the bulk of the compute time in NumPy, there likely is no reason to worry about speeding it up using a just-in-time compiler or similar modifications to your setup. As explained in more detail [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-fast-numpy-really-is-e9111df44347), NumPy is fast due to it implementing compute-intensive tasks in compiled languages, so it saves you from worrying about that and abstracts it away.

Depending on what exactly you are planning to do, it is *possible* that your efficiency could be improved by [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing), but this is not something I would worry about yet.

To end on a more general note: while optimizing code efficiency is of course very important, it is imperative to do so carefully and deliberately. As Donald Knuth is famous for saying ["premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#:%7E:text=premature%20optimization%20is%20the%20root%20of%20all%20evil%20(or%20at%20least%20most%20of%20it)%20in%20programming). See [this stack exchange thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) for some more discussion on this.

Comment: Yes, I used cProfile and identified the most time consuming functions: *np.pad* and the aggregate function (the *func* parameter of *block_reduce*) - which calls the *reduce* method of *np.ufunc*. For my application, parallelization may bring improvement as we could apply the aggregate function to the array blocks independently. But it's hard for me to see how to make it, because there is no for loop here (I can't see how to make use of libraries like multiprocessing, joblib or ray without for loops).

Comment: When you say "the aggregate function (the func parameter of block_reduce) - which calls the reduce method of np.ufunc", are the aggregate functions in question built-in numpy functions or are they numpy functions you created yourself through the numpy vectorize decorator or some other means to create your own ufunc.

Comment: I mean built-in numpy functions like *np.mean*, *np.max*, etc. For information, I've tried to implement my own *block_reduce* function which calls a helper function decorated with `numba.njit(parallel=True)`. That helper function includes two for loops (one outer loop and one inner loop) and it somehow replaces the *view_as_blocks* function. Execution time is now halved. I was expecting more but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @OES Okay I understand. I just asked because I wanted to confirm that your aggregate functions were using compiled C code and not just regular Python code because people sometimes make ufunc's which run in pure Python without realizing it. I am glad to hear you ended up finding a satisfactory solution although it's unfortunate that the speedup is not as fast as you wanted.